# Will ConversationBufferWindowMemory will be applicable to each of the chains ConversationalRetrievalChain, RetrievalQA, RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain

Tags: python, memory, langchain, chain

I want to use ConversationBufferWindowMemory in my code. will this memory support all of the chains[ConversationalRetrievalChain, RetrievalQA, RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain]